# Draw calendar events

Tags: vue.js, dependencies, vue-component

I'm currently making a resource management tool where I need to draw events on a calendar like Google Calendar does. I'm making this calendar in Vue and I have also tried to implement the new Vuetify calendar component but I can't get it to work the way I want so I started to make it on my own.

Now my question: 
Is there any vue dependency available that lets you draw events (rectangles) on a calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify's calendar gives You almost full control of the calendar including day squares (You call them rectangles) via scoped slots. You can make Your own layout and logic.

If this is not enough for You, try checking out Vue-Full-Calendar (https://github.com/CroudTech/vue-fullcalendar) or Toast UI Calendar (https://ui.toast.com/tui-calendar/) - my personal favorite.

Comment: Thanks! I look into it. :-)